# Using Stitch to import data to Postgres database, not all selected fields are being replicated

Tags: postgresql, etl, data

Has anyone has trouble with replicating tables/fields from the service [Stitch](https://www.stitchdata.com/)?  I've used this for various data sources in the past and I'm currently having issues with the platform [Kustomer](https://www.kustomer.com/).  The tables exists in my database, but some ofthe fields I'm looking for are not being replicated.  I looked through the logs and I'm not finding any answers, not sure where to troubleshoot next.